# 3 layer function and use the inner most one to output the result

Tags: python, function

This is more like a brain teaser than a practical deed. I have created a 3 layer function stacking onto each other. I can't tell python to add 3 given numeric arguments together by only the inner most function, can anyone help?

```
    def first(x):
        def second(y):
            def third(z):
                return(x+y+z)
            return third

    third1 = first(1)
    third2 = second(2)
    ....... get stuck here .......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue with this code is that function `second` can't be called. It is not in same lexical scope as the code that tries to call it.

Example that works:

```
def first(x):
    def second(y):
        def third(z):
            return x+y+z
        return third
    return second

f = first(1)
s = f(2)
print s(4)  # 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You need each function to return its 'child' function, and then keep a reference to that to then call in the next step - something like:

```
def first(x):
    print(x)
    def second(y):
        print(y)
        def third(z):
            print(z)
            return(x+y+z)
        return third
    return second

two = first(1)
three = second(2)
print(three(3))
```

Comment: Nitpick: these are functions, not methods

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The question indentation implied they were part of a (not shown) class, so I guessed they were methods? (no, not really, just a thinko on my part - will fix :-))

Answer (score 0):

Just like `second` needs to return `third`, `first` needs to return `second`.

```
def first(x):
    def second(y):
        def third(z):
            return(x+y+z)
        return third
    return second
```

Further, you can't call `second` directly, because that is a name local to `first`. You need to call the return value of `first`:

```
f1 = first(1) # f1 is second wrapped around x == 1
f2 = f1(2)    # f2 is third wrapped around x == 1 and y == 2
f3 = f2(3)    # f3 is 1 + 2 + 3 == 6
```